# Best approach to building a kiosk app with views that change on timer

Tags: angularjs

I have an app i'm building that has about 6 different views, each with their own controller.

I'm wanting to switch each view automatically after x seconds, and once it's at the end to go back to the start.

I also want to be able to pause the timer if you click on a pause button.

What i have (and im sure there's a way better approach) at the moment, is a timer in each controller that stops once the view changes.

```
$rootScope.homeProm = $timeout(function(){
    $location.path('page2');
},12000);
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(homeProm);
});
```

Would using states be better in this scenario? And would a service be better to use for the timer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$destroy` of `$scope`, that would make more sense, As controller gets deregister with DOM it call your desired code. Basically this block has been used to clean up the code.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(homeProm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will have a wrapper controller:

```
<div ng-controller="WrapperController">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
<div>
```

Each view will have their own controller and the WrapperController will handle changing view and stopping. I will not have duplicate code in each controller.

This is what I would do first, maybe there are another better solution.